# WP8 ListPicker w/ SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app, which is basically a port of my existing Silverlight app. On one screen in the SL version, I have 10 ComboBox controls that default to nothing selected, forcing the user to make a selection before saving the item. That works great (this is my company's bug tracking application, so I want the users to be forced to make these selections, else they'll leave in a default, which will likely be incorrect).

In WP8, the powers that be seem to want us to use their ListPicker from the WPToolkit (since there is no ComboBox there or in the default controls). However, this is more a ListBox that supports SelectedIndex but not SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath. I've been using an index property in my viewmodel(this is kind of a pain since the model loads async, but I've been working around that..), but I have to default it to an actual option, which negates the business rule of forcing a selection.

I've also tried essentially copying the source code for ListPicker and have it inherit from Selector (the base control just inherits from ItemsControl), but that won't work as the Selector constructor is internal.

It seems like what I want to do is add support for SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath. Is that possible? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Joe, if what you are trying to do is just add a default value to a ListPicker then add the default value as first option: `<toolkit:ListPicker>
                    <sys:String>default option</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>other options..</sys:String>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>`